# Implementing many to many relationship with opportunity product

Tags: apex, visualforce, opportunity-lineitem

I am looking to implement a many to many relationship between the Opportunity Product and a custom object. This can't be done in the standard way with a junction object as there seem to be limitations around the Opportunity Product. I did find a way to do it with an intermediate object but it was a bit complicated from a user experience point of view. Also, on the Opportunity Product, it does not appear to be possible to have an inline Visualforce page or a button to a Visualforce page. I am guessing re-implementing that whole standard page in Visualforce or doing something with a Javascript button might be on the only way, but it seems like a lot of effort. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify the scenario a bit more it is to add one or more promotions against an Opportunity Product, where promotions are represented by a custom promotion object. Users need to be able to report on promotions used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to say you're correct here.  I've actually worked with clients before where they've replaced Opportunities/Opportunity Products completely with custom objects due to these limitations.  There are several ideas in the Idea Exchange to add functionality for Opportunity Products, but neither has been accepted:

Related lists for Opportunity Products is under consideration:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BroaAAC

Allowing lookups TO Opportunity Products is below threshold:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrfaAAC

The simplest approach around this is creating that intermediate object - the Opportunity Product looks up to the intermediate object, then you create a junction between that and your custom object.  As you said, not great for user experience.

While you cannot send the user to a Visualforce page directly, you can use a URL-based button to direct the user to a Visualforce page, using merge fields to pass the Id in as a parameter.  So that limitation can be overcome fairly easily.

If you have any more details of the business function of this custom object, perhaps I can come up with a little bit more.

Comment: N.B. veering off Opportunity Product has all sorts of consequences as I'm sure you pointed out to your clients: (1) Can make integration with appexchange packages much harder as they expect Opportunity Products to be present; (2) Breaks Quote sync to Opportunity; (3) Breaks Collaborative Forecasting are just three things that come to mind